# Integrating Google OAuth2 API in Angular2 Typescript APP

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth-2.0, typescript-typings

I try to integrate the Google oauth2 API and the Calender API into a Angular2 application. I cound not find any running samle that helps me todo the integration.

Anyone knows a running sample?

Regards Hacki

Comment: have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-oauth2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Installing

From the root of your Apache Cordova project, execute the following:

npm install ng2-cordova-oauth --save
This will install ng2-cordova-oauth and its dependencies.

Injecting:

There are 2 types of entities in the library: Platform (i.e., Cordova, Browser) and Provider (i.e., Facebook, LinkedIn, etc.). Each provider has it's own class. You need to inject the Platform class into every class in which you wish to use them. For example, if you wish to use Facebook oauth in a particular class, it would look something like:

```
import {Facebook, Google} from 'ng2-cordova-oauth/core';
import {OauthBrowser} from 'ng2-cordova-oauth/platform/browser'
```

// or

```
import {OauthCordova} from 'ng2-cordova-oauth/platform/cordova'


import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController, Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Facebook, Google, LinkedIn} from "ng2-cordova-oauth/core";
import {OauthCordova} from 'ng2-cordova-oauth/platform/cordova';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    private oauth: OauthCordova = new OauthCordova();
    private facebookProvider: Facebook = new Facebook({
      clientId: "CLIENT_ID_HERE",
      appScope: ["email"]
    })

    constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, private platform: Platform) { }

    public facebook() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.oauth.logInVia(this.facebookProvider).then(success => {
                console.log("RESULT: " + JSON.stringify(success));
            }, error => {
                console.log("ERROR: ", error);
            });
        });
    }

}
```

Try this link https://github.com/nraboy/ng2-cordova-oauth